# jailbroke cydia app development without mac

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, ubuntu, jailbreak

I want to ask if there is any possibility how to develop app for jailbroken Iphone without using a mac, in a way that I'd programmed application in Windows or Ubuntu and would compile a program on my jailbroken iPhone. I using a pc with  Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual boot so no matter which system i use. I would especially like some good environment for Objective C,because I know that it is the ability to program the application in Java and then import it, but I think that in the future it would be a bad habit :) I was looking for lot of simmilar questions but no one took into consideration the possibility of compilation on the phone.... but if I'm stupid, please navigate me to the right place and close this issue. Thanks in advance for all the answers and sorry for my english :)

Comment: Try to look at hackintosh, it what i'm using and this is not that complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option for jailbreak development without a Mac is to compile your code on the iPhone itself over SSH! You can use Cydia to install an OpenSSH server on your iPhone. Then, log in using ssh from the Ubuntu terminal, or PuTTY on Windows.

Once SSH is up-and-running, you'll need to install a toolchain on your device. Try the "[iOS Toolchain](http://apt.thebigboss.org/onepackage.php?bundleid=org.coolstar.iostoolchain&db=)" package from the BigBoss repository in Cydia.

You should then be able to install Theos onto the device, though you may need to find iOS SDK headers in order to compile against iOS frameworks. The official headers can be found as part of Xcode (in a folder called iPhoneOS7.1.sdk), but you could also potentially use [dumped headers](https://github.com/MP0w/iOS-Headers).

[Here](http://www.iapphacks.net/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=2427) is a brief tutorial for how to do this.

Additionally, it's possible to set up an iOS development environment on Windows. See [this guide](http://sharedinstance.net/2013/12/build-on-windows/)!

Answer (score 1):

I got into iOS development on a Hackintosh, as was suggested by Oleg. What was omitted from Oleg's comment was a way to get started, which is why I created this answer.

I started [here (OSx86 Project)](http://www.osx86project.org/) and got my first Hackintosh set up on a Toshiba Satellite laptop. The better your hardware resembles actual Apple hardware, the better your experience will be. With an AMD chip (or one without SSE3), you will have a harder time.

The page linked above will give you an option for the [InsanelyMac forum](http://www.insanelymac.com/) (awesome resources there) and the [OSx86 Wiki](http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

There are other ways of doing iOS development without a Mac, but this is the route I went. I do recommend you eventually purchase a Mac for iOS development, as everything will work the way it is supposed to.

If you do not want to take the Hackintosh route and just want to start developing apps that run on jailbroken iOS devices, check out [the pages offered by the Cydia team here](http://cydia.saurik.com/faq/developing.html).